# Emit unmanaged call with stringbuilder marshalling

Tags: c#, unmanaged, reflection.emit

I want to call an unmanaged function with a `Reflection.Emit` generated code.

I have a dll which defines the following native C function.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI ChangeString(wchar_t *lpBuf, int nSize)
 {
     return swprintf_s(lpBuf, nSize, L"Value=%s\n", L"Something");
 }
```

Then I go through defining a C# interface with a method for the above function.

```
public interface IMyNative {   

    int ChangeString(StringBuilder sb, int size);
}
```

From this point on, I have a simple `MakeNative` function that defines a a type using `Reflection.Emit` which implements the `IMyNative` interface. In order to generate method that corresponds to the native call I do the following:

```
// MakeNative function, for brevity only revelant part is below.
MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ChangeString",
     MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
     typeof(int), new Type[] { typeof(StringBuilder), typeof(int) });

ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

// 0th arg is object itself, ignore
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg1);  // first arg
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg2);  // second arg

// AddrOfNativeFunction is found using LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, AddrOfNativeFunction);
il.EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli, CallingConvetion.StdCall, typeof(int), new Type[] { typeof(StringBuilder), typeof(int) };
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Then I try to call `ChangeString` method using `StringBuilder`:

```
IMyNative impl = MakeNative();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
impl.ChangeString(sb, 100);
```

But program crashes with an `AccessViolationException`. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Bypassing the pinvoke marshaller is a drastically bad idea.  Using a delegate is a rock-hard requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could possibly be wrong?

You're passing the address of a `StringBuilder` to a function called through a pointer. This is probably unverifiable IL. Your native function cannot make sense of a pointer to a managed class.

You probably meant to use the usual PInvoke marshalling logic, but you are not using PInvoke. For that reason you don't get marshalling.

Use PInvoke. Emit a PInvoke method and call it.

Comment: @mo5 you can also call it without marshalling. You'd need to obtain a `char*` and pass it directly.